# How to implement an iterator in class prototype in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, iterator

I have a TypeScript class `List` which is imported.  (It acts like a Singly Linked List).  I am trying to implement an iterator for the class.

```
List.prototype[Symbol.iterator] = function* gen() {
...
};
```

However, TypeScript server says "Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'symbol' can't be used to index type 'List'".

What is the proper way of implementing and using an iterator for a TypeScript class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple example of a default iterator on a class:

```
class List {
    *[Symbol.iterator]() {
        yield "Foo";
        yield "Bar";
    }
}


const list = new List();
for (let element of list) {
    console.log(`element ${element}`)
}
```

If the List already exists and you cannot directly add members to it, you can extend it through a prototype. Before you can assign the member to the prototype, you must declare the new member via an interface:

```
// This is defined elsewhere and cannot be modified
class List {
   // ...
}


// This is our code that extends it by adding a default iterator
interface List {
    [Symbol.iterator]: () => Iterator<string>;
}

List.prototype[Symbol.iterator] = function* () {
    yield "Foo";
    yield "Bar";
};


const list = new List();
for (let element of list) {
    console.log(`element ${element}`)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the sample code!  However, I hadn't previously clarified, class `List` is imported, and hence, I had to use prototype inheritance.  To implement it within the class, I would have to create `class NewList extends List`.

How can I avoid creating new classes?

Comment: @acagastya Turns out that it is possible to do what you're asking. I've added the alternative syntax (using a prototype) to the answer.

Comment: Without the interface, tsserver was giving an error.  The interface fixes the problem!  Thank you very much!